# AngularJS Foreach not waiting

Tags: angularjs

I have am using angularjs trying to upload multiple files to my sharepoint API so what I did I use foreach statement with $q.all to wait for everything to finish uploading but somehow my code is already considered resolved on the first upload of file.

factory.UploadFilesByBatch = function(arrayBuffer, folderName) {
        var promises = [];

```
    angular.forEach(arrayBuffer, function(item) {
        // factory.GetFormDigest().then(function(data) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // promises.push(deferred);

        console.log("UploadFilesByBatch Try - " + item.fileName + "Uploading")
        $http({
            url: webUrl + "web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" + folderLocation + "')/files/add(overwrite=true, url='" + item.fileName + "')",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": xrequestDigest,
                "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            data: item.fileBuffer,
            transformRequest: []
        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log("UploadFilesByBatch Success - " + item.fileName + "Uploaded")
            item.sharepointFileLocation = result.data.d.ServerRelativeUrl;
            deferred.resolve(item);

        }, function(result, status) {
            console.log("UploadFilesByBatch Error - " + item.fileName + "Failed")
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
            deferred.reject(result);
        });
        promises.push(deferred);

        // })

    })
    return $q.all(promises);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not quite using the $q.all correctly.  You want to push the actual promise into your array of promises.  You'll also want to get rid of all of the deferred stuff, the $http call already is a promise so you can push that directly into your promise array.

Instead of `promises.push(deferred);`  You want to do

```
promises.push($http({
                url: webUrl + "web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" + folderLocation + "')/files/add(overwrite=true, url='" + item.fileName + "')",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue,
                    "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },
                data: item.fileBuffer,
                transformRequest: []
            })
);
```

This will leave you with an array of promises.  You can then use `$q.all(promises)` to iterate over the results like so:

```
$q.all(promises).then(function(promiseResults) {
  // promiseResult is an array of the return values from the $http request in the order they were pushed into the promises array
  angular.forEach(promiseResults, function(result, resultIndex) {
    // Whatever you wanted to do to each result here
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply it solves the issue. Now what if I wanted to return a different object on the return? As you can see after each upload I am trying modify the property of "arrayBuffer" which I wanted to return instead.

Comment: Oops nvm I think I solved it :) Thanks for the help again man your the best

Comment: @SharePointLovesMe if you got the answer please accept it

Comment: @SharePointLovesMe Glad I could help out!